# Please explain transform.rotate in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can somebody explain why this method can't work as a normal fps camera movement? I set Z-Axis to 0 but it changes when I test it. I can use Quaternion but I really can't understand why this method doesn't work.

```
void onCameraLook() {
    mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensitivity;
    mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensitivity;

    transform.Rotate(-mouseY, mouseX, 0, Space.Self);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `Rotate` with `Space.Self` you will rotate the object around its local axes. 
 For a "*normal fps camera*" this is fine for vertical rotation, you want to rotate around the local x/right axis, but for horizontal rotation you want the object to rotate around a global y/up axis. For a more detailed post see [rotating an object on two axes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir).

 
So your code should be:

```
void onCameraLook() {
    mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensitivity;
    mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensitivity;

    transform.Rotate(-mouseY, 0, 0, Space.Self);
    transform.Rotate(0, mouseX, 0, Space.World);        
}
```